# C++(SFML?) Activate something for x seconds, without freezing the whole program

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

I want to give my Sprite some extra speed when you press the spacebar for 3 seconds. After that you should wait 10 Seconds before using it again.
I tried using SFML's Time, but the clock starts right away as the program starts so it starts anyway....

Short Question: How can I delay a function without freezing the program like Sleep() does.

Code(console only for dev progess as it slows):

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
using namespace std;
sf::Clock ClockSpeedFunc, Cooldown;
ClockSpeedFunc.restart();
bool Timer, CooldownTimer = false;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "SFML WORK!");
sf::Texture texture;

if (!texture.loadFromFile("PlayerTexture.jpg"))
{
    std::cout << "Error loading PlayerTexture.jpg" << std::endl;
}

sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(texture);

sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
float PlayerSpeed = 0.1;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();

            break;

        }
    }
    //###Controls ::
    //If W is pressed, move upwards
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -PlayerSpeed));
    }
    //If A is pressed, move left
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(-PlayerSpeed, 0));
    }
    //If S is pressed, move downwards
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, PlayerSpeed));
    }
    //If D is pressed, move right
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(PlayerSpeed, 0));
    }
    //If Space is pressed, set Timer to true and set Speed to 0.5
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) && CooldownTimer == false) {
        cout << "Turbo started" << endl;
        Timer = true;
        CooldownTimer == false;
        PlayerSpeed = 0.5;
    }
    //If Timer = true, start a clock
    if (Timer = true) {
        sf::Clock ClockSpeedFunc;
    }
    //aafter 3 Seconds set Playerspeed back to 0.1
    //Set Cooldowntimer to true and restart timer clock.


        sf::Time elapsed1 = ClockSpeedFunc.getElapsedTime();
        sf::Time elapsed2 = Cooldown.getElapsedTime();

    if (elapsed1.asSeconds() >= 3) {
            PlayerSpeed = 0.1;
            cout << "Turbo ended." << endl;
            ClockSpeedFunc.restart();
            CooldownTimer = true;
    }if (CooldownTimer == true) {
        cout << "Cooldown started" << endl;
        sf::Clock Cooldown;
    }if (elapsed2.asSeconds() >= 10) {
        cout << "Cooldown ended" << endl;
        Cooldown.restart();
        CooldownTimer = false;
    }

    //Draw everything
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
}
```

}`

Comment: "Short Question: How can I delay a function without freezing the program like Sleep() does." Imo the easiest way to do that is to implement a job queue. Though that's over complicated to solve your problem, the quickest thing would be to restart `ClockSpeedFunc` whenever the spacebar is released or the `Cooldown` timer is under 10 seconds, and restart `Cooldown` whenever `ClockSpeedFunc` exceeds 3 seconds.

Comment: Try to research Finite State Machines. It sounds like you need a simple FSM for this.

Comment: There are many small mistakes in your code that make it hard to give you an easy answer without going through it line-by-line. I'd suggest you reduce your sample to a single key and a single countdown and ask the question with that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you do not use "using namespace". That is a bad habit. And why did you have a #include  there. I did not need it.

It is not part of the problem, but I highly recommend to have a look on https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ and manage your delta time.

I think I would use a class for this. But here you can see how to use it with states. I added some comments in the code so you can see what I did.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>

// Define the different states of the player
enum class m_State{
  POWERUP, NORMAL, COOLDOWN
};

int main(){
  sf::Clock m_Clock;

  // Record elapsed time of power up
  float m_SecondsSincePowerUp;

  // Set initial state
  m_State m_State = m_State::NORMAL;

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "SFML WORK!");
  sf::Texture texture;

  if (!texture.loadFromFile("PlayerTexture.jpg")){
      std::cout << "Error loading PlayerTexture.jpg" << std::endl;
  }

  sf::Sprite sprite;
  sprite.setTexture(texture);

  sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
  sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
  sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
  sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(50, 40));
  float PlayerSpeed = 0.1;

  while (window.isOpen()){
    sf::Time elapsedTime = m_Clock.restart();
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)){
      switch (event.type){
        case sf::Event::Closed:
          window.close();
          break;
        }
    }
    //###Controls ::
    //If W is pressed, move upwards
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -PlayerSpeed));
    }
    //If A is pressed, move left
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(-PlayerSpeed, 0));
    }
    //If S is pressed, move downwards
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, PlayerSpeed));
    }
    //If D is pressed, move right
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
        sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(PlayerSpeed, 0));
    }
    //If Space is pressed, set Timer to true and set Speed to 0.5
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) && (m_State == m_State::NORMAL)){
        std::cout << "Turbo started" << std::endl;
        // Set state to PowerUp
        m_State = m_State::POWERUP;
        PlayerSpeed = 0.5;
    }

    // If state is PowerUp count the seconds in a variable
    if (m_State == m_State::POWERUP){
      // Add elapsed time in seconds
      m_SecondsSincePowerUp += elapsedTime.asSeconds();

      // After 3 seconds switch the state to Cooldown
      if (m_SecondsSincePowerUp > 3.0f){
        std::cout << "Turbo ended." << std::endl;
        m_State = m_State::COOLDOWN;
        PlayerSpeed = 0.1;
      }
    }

    // After 10 seconds switch to normal
    if (m_State == m_State::COOLDOWN){
      m_SecondsSincePowerUp += elapsedTime.asSeconds();
      if (m_SecondsSincePowerUp > 10.0f){
        std::cout << "Cooldown ended." << std::endl;
        m_State = m_State::NORMAL;
        m_SecondsSincePowerUp = 0;
      }
    }

    //Draw everything
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a thread to create a sleep while normal code continues to execute in unison. They are quite complex for a full explanation but look up an example and see if you think it's worth trying to implement for use with this.

Comment: Not sure i'd recommend that. Especially dedicating an entire thread, there'd be a of code complexity like you say. But if anymore of the program were to be multi-threaded, there'd be an unnecessarily large performance hit from context switches and a potentially large hit from things like critical sections.